# SQL SUM column value once per one-to-many relationship ID

Tags: sql

I have a table similar to the below called Payment. I want to run a query which will give me:

count of payments, sum of OrderAmounts and sum of TotalPaymentAmount (here's the issue)

```
--------------------------------------------------
| PaymentID | OrderAmount | TotalPaymentAmount   |
--------------------------------------------------
|      1    |     10      |          10          |
--------------------------------------------------
|      2    |     15      |          25          |
--------------------------------------------------
|      2    |     10      |          25          |
--------------------------------------------------
|      3    |     30      |          125         |
--------------------------------------------------
|      3    |     10      |          125         |
--------------------------------------------------
|      3    |     70      |          125         |
--------------------------------------------------
|      3    |     15      |          125         |
--------------------------------------------------
```

The query:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(PaymentID)
  ,SUM(OrderAmount)
  ,SUM(TotalPaymentAmount)
FROM Payment
```

This produces:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| PaymentID | OrderAmount | TotalPaymentAmount   |
--------------------------------------------------
|      7    |     160     |         560          |
--------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, and as expected, we have SUM'd each entry from the TotalPaymentAmount column producing elevated figures. Instead, I'd like to run the same query but this time on SUM the TotalPaymentAmount once per unique paymentID.

Any suggestions?

thank you as always

Comment: Just group this by the paymentid then it will sum the details based on the grouping

Comment: It would then SUM the Orders incorrectly I believe. I want OrderAmount to sum naturally, and TotalPaymentAmount only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pre-aggregate the data:

```
select sum(numpayments), sum(amount), sum(totalpayments)
from (select p.paymentid, count(*) as numpayments, sum(orderamount) as amount,
             max(TotalPaymentAmount) as totalpayments
      from payment p
      group by p.paymentid
     ) p;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  COUNT(PaymentID)
  ,SUM(OrderAmount)
  ,SUM(TotalPaymentAmount)
FROM Payment
group by PaymentID
```

should work I think.